# Client cannot mount: "mount.nfs4: Protocol not supported"

Tags: nfs4

I am running nfs4 only on both server and client.  I am not sure what I changed recently, but I can no longer mount an exported file system which I used to be able to mount.  I have just upgraded the client machine from Fedora 31 to 32... but I swear nfs was still working immediately after the upgrade.

At the client end I do:

```
  # mount /foo
  mount.nfs4: Protocol not supported
```

The `/etc/fstab` has not been changed.  There is nothing already mounted at `/foo`.  I get the same result issuing `mount.nfs4` by hand.

Using wireshark at the client I can see absolutely nothing being sent to the nfs server (or being received from same).  Using tcpdump I can see nothing at the server end, from before the client is rebooted to after the attempts to mount.  So I'm guessing this is a client issue ?

I can see nothing in the logs.  I have failed to find anything to wind up the logging level for client-side mounting.

Can anyone point me at ways to discover what the client is doing (or not doing) ?

---

As requested...

`dmesg` mentions of nfs|NFS:

```
[    7.987799] systemd[1]: Starting Preprocess NFS configuration convertion...
[    7.993220] systemd[1]: nfs-convert.service: Succeeded.
[    7.993342] systemd[1]: Finished Preprocess NFS configuration convertion.
[   12.484481] RPC: Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel transport module.
```

And `fstab` on the client:

```
foo:/ /foo nfs4 noauto,sec=sys,proto=tcp,clientaddr=xx.xx.xx.xx,port=1001  0 0
```

The client has more than one IP.  The server wishes to obscure the fact that it offers nfs.  To make that easier it does nfs4 only.  FWIW `netstat` on the server gives (edited for clarity):

```
Prot  R-Q S-Q  Local Address      Foreign Address  State    PID/Program
tcp    0   0   xx.xx.xx.xx:1001   0.0.0.0:*        LISTEN   -
tcp    0   0   0.0.0.0:111        0.0.0.0:*        LISTEN   1/systemd
tcp    0   0   0.0.0.0:1002       0.0.0.0:*        LISTEN   815/rpc.statd
```

I thought nfs4 required just the one port... but systemd seems to wake up port 111 anyway.  There is also rpc.statd.

The configuration of the server used to work...  Also, the client is not sending anything to the server at all on any port !

And the `exports` on the server:

```
/ bar(fsid=0,no_subtree_check,sec=sys,rw,no_root_squash,insecure,crossmnt)
```

Where `bar` is in the server's `\etc\hosts` file.

I did `showmount -e foo` on the client:

```
clnt_create: RPC: Program not registered
```

Wireshark tells me that the client poked the server on port 111 asking for `MOUNT (100005) Version 3 tcp` and received 'no' response.  The poke for `udp` received the same answer.  Since the server is configured nfs4 only, I guess this is not a surprise ?  I note that `showmount` does not ask for Version 4... but I don't know if you'd expect it to ?

Comment: Check for anything interesting in `dmesg`.

Comment: Can you add the exact entry from the fstab

Comment: And while you're at it: `/etc/exports` from the server and the output of `showmount -e <your-server-address>` when run on the client.

Comment: Thank you... I've updated the question.

Comment: 111 is not needed for nfs4, you can remove `rpcbind`. Probably it'll help troubleshoot. Something that worries me is that port 2049, the default for nfs4 does not seem to be there on your server. Can you post the output of `sudo ss -tulp` command?

Comment: I would be disappointed if port 2049 were open, since I am deliberately configuring the server on 1001 only (and that used to work !).  Also, the client is not trying to reach port 2049 at any time, not even when the client boots.  Nor is it trying to reach port 1001 (the configured port for nfs4, tcp).  Nor is it trying to reach port 111.  `mount.nfs4` on the client simply refuses to do anything at all, and I cannot see why :-(  Is there some module that should be loaded ?  I have done `modprobe nfs`.  I have nfs and nfs4 in `/proc/filesystems`.

Answer (score 5):

OK... so I downloaded the source and started poking around with `strace`.

The problem was that I had been over-enthusiastic in `/etc/nfsmount.conf`, specifically:

1. for nfs4 it is a mistake to set any of these:

   ```
    mounthost
    mountaddr 
    mountvers
    mountproto
   ```

   in `/etc/nfsmount.conf` to anything at all (that includes setting `mountvers=4` and setting `mountproto=tcp`).

   If (like me) you are stupid enough to do this, the code sets `errno=EPROTONOSUPPORT` and returns an error... as if `socket()` had failed.  [The error reporting mechanics don't seem to be aware of this, and reports the error in a 'default' manner, using `strerror()`.]
2. it is also a mistake to set `mounvers` in `/etc/nfsmount.conf`.

   Again, if (like me) you are stupid enough misspell `mountvers` and put `mounvers=4` in `/etc/nfsmount.conf`, you will get:

   ```
   # mount.nfs4 -v -o noauto,sec=sys,proto=tcp,port=1001 foo:/ /foo
   mount.nfs4: timeout set for Fri Sep 11 16:24:09 2020
   mount.nfs4: trying text-based options 'sec=sys,proto=tcp,port=1001,mounvers=4,vers=4.2,addr=xx,clientaddr=xx'
   mount.nfs4: mount(2): Invalid argument
   ....
   ```

   ...which is I guess to be expected.

Ah well, I had nothing better to do for a couple of days :-(

Comment: nfs4 doesn't use *mountd* as it has pseudo file system that does the job.